# number of parse calls allowed in trial version of jep jar

Tags: java

I am using jep for evaluating expressions but getting following exception

```
15:01:00,819 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-3) com.singularsys.jep.ParseException: Trial version limitation: Number of parse calls exceeded

15:01:00,819 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-3)  at com.singularsys.jep.Jep.parse(Unknown Source)

15:01:00,819 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-3)  at com.singularsys.jep.Jep.parse(Unknown Source)
```

from above it is clear that the number of parse calls are exceeding than the allowed limit.
For now i have 28 expressions.
Does any one have idea of what is the maximum number of parse calls does jep allows in trial version.
Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check JEval which is free. http://jeval.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Homepage of [Jep](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/download-trial.php):

```
The trial releases parse up to 50 expressions, after which an exception is thrown.
```